# How can i use Macro to pass JDBC Driver name in Database operator stage in Datafusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm trying to use the Data fusion Database stage to connect to a SAP HANA db.
I imported the jdbc driver and as shown in the image I attach, it is now possible to select the jdbc driver name just imported (in this case SAP_HANA). This way everything works.
However, I need to create a dynamic pipeline and I would like to use the macros for the JDBC Driver Name instead of selecting it from the drop list. I configured an argument setter and created a json with a type.driver parameter containing the string 'SAP_HANA'.
I tried passing the argument inside the JDBC Driver Name parameter of the stage database by inserting ${type.driver} but it doesn't work. Why does it only work by selecting SAP_HANA from the dropList? Has anyone tried to do something similar?

I imported the jdbc driver and as shown in the image I attach, it is now possible to select the jdbc driver name just imported (in this case SAP_HANA). This way everything works.
However, I need to create a dynamic pipeline and I would like to use the macros for the JDBC Driver Name instead of selecting it from the drop list. I configured an argument setter and created a json with a type.driver parameter containing the string 'SAP_HANA'.
I tried passing the argument inside the JDBC Driver Name parameter of the stage database by inserting ${type.driver} but it doesn't work. Why does it only work by selecting SAP_HANA from the dropList? Has anyone tried to do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Have you successfully attached the image? I could not see it from the question. Could you please try uploading it again?

Currently I believe dynamic jdbc driver using macros is not supported in Data Fusion. In order deploy a pipeline, it needs to pass validation and be certain about the jdbc driver to use at the Database stage.

You can please try using `Conditional` in `Conditions and Actions` in the pipeline studio and put desiring conditional checks to choose which jdbc driver to use.